# Ненужное возвращаемое значение функции

Tags: c++

Имеется функция _getch(), которая используется просто для паузы перед выходом из функции (ожидание нажатия клавиши от пользователя), то есть возвращаемое значение мне не нужно и я не присваиваю его никакой переменной. Соответственно выскакивают варнинги "Пропущено возвращаемое значение _getch()".

Поэтому вызываю эту функцию так: `(void)_getch()`.

Что происходит при такой записи и вообще, можно ли так делать?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Вглядываясь в ваш nick поясню -- обычно возвращаемое функцией значение находится в машинном регистре (например, `R0` в MIPS или `x0` в Aarch-64, или `rax` в X86-64). В вашем случае оно просто никак не используется, т.е. не пересылается в другой регистр или не записывается в память